# JS, Express: Failed to lookup view in directory regardless following guide

Tags: javascript, express

Im following this guide:
https://appdividend.com/2017/06/18/node-js-express-tutorial/

And did a lot of research but somehow can't get it working.

My folder structure:
[image]

My code:

```
// app.js

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = 3000;

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('Server is running on port:', port);
})
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('Hello Express');
});


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

var itemRouter = express.Router();

app.use('/items', itemRouter);

itemRouter.route('/').get(function (req, res) {
  res.render('items');
});

itemRouter.route('/single').get(function (req, res) {
  res.render('singleItem');
});
```

My output:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "items" in views directory "C:\Users\Karol\views"
    at Function.render (C:\Users\Karol\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:580:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\Karol\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
    at C:\Users\Karol\Desktop\CB\app.js:27:7
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Karol\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Karol\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Karol\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Karol\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\Karol\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Karol\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Karol\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
```

This is what I get when I visit `localhost:port/items` (replace port with actual port number).

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem about resolving `views` path. Try to require `path` module after express

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var port = 3000;
```

and after setting ejs template add this:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.resolve(__dirname, 'views'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace :

```
app.use('/items', itemRouter);

itemRouter.route('/').get(function (req, res) {
  res.render('items');
});

itemRouter.route('/single').get(function (req, res) {
  res.render('singleItem');
});
```

by :

```
itemRouter.route('/items/').get(function (req, res) {
  res.render('items');
});

itemRouter.route('/items/single').get(function (req, res) {
  res.render('singleItem');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var path = require('path');
```

Try this to set the directory for the public like this.

```
app.set('view_engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname,'/views'))
```

It will get the project directory and set the views path.